# Java's equivalent of .Net's WebClient

Tags: java, .net

What is the equivalent method or code construction to what WebClient is in .Net? [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the description of it:

> Provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a resource identified by a URI.

Basically I need to know how would I put parameters to the request, just like they do in .Net:

```
WebClient client = this.WebClient();
client.QueryString.Add("param1", "name");
client.QueryString.Add("param2", "lastname");
```

Comment: @pst - to quote the OP: "But this is only about replacement for HttpWebRequest, not WebClient."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This concept is used with REST web services.
The resources can be accessed through a URI.
Here is a helpful link:
[Rest web services - GO TO SECTION 5.5(Create a client)](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html#crud_client)

SECTION 5.5

Comment: The link is no longer valid, could you update it?